# WebStorm autosaves sass files and webpack-dev-server auto loads them?

Tags: intellij-idea, webpack, webstorm, css-loader

I'm not even sure, because it doesn't happen in js files.

So as I'm writing in scss files, after a debounce of what seems like 300ms, without saving the file, webpack-dev-server hot reloads the sass bundle.

I don't know what other info to provide. Ask me anything? :}

Comment: do you use File Watcher to transpile your Scss to css? If yes, try disabling 'Immediate synchronization' in File Watcher preferences. Also, does the problem only occur if debug session is active?

Comment: @lena No sass File Watcher, and yes! it only happens in debug session. If I use 'run' to start the webpack dev server, the auto saving doesn't happen. But I need to run it in debug mode so I can have elmlang file watcher output errors in the run pane, and auto-close when i fix them. If I have the webpack dev server in the run pane too, it wouldn't auto-close.

Comment: I see, thanks:) Problem is likely caused by Live Edit - it auto-saves files on editing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try disabling `Live Edit` plugin. Related ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7093

Comment: For the ones who care, this is what you are losing: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/live-editing-of-html-css-and-javascript.html